# Firebase functions deploy more than one function not working on windows

Tags: windows, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy more than one function, but not all, on firebase CLI with a command like:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2
```

It doesn't work when I try to do it from PowerShell, due to the following error:

```
functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: func1 functions
```

When I run it from another linux-like terminal, such as git bash, terminal I can and it doesn't throw any error.

Does anyone know if there is some special syntax to deploy functions from PowerShell or if it's simply not possible?

Comment: Are you using the latest CLI ? In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the latest version of the Firebase CLI. It's a good practice to frequently update the CLI to its latest version

Comment: You may log an issue on the [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) GitHub.